# Removing x,y axis points from plt.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 3 datasets in the one image with arbitrary units. I have done this using a loop:

```
fig,axs=plt.subplots(3,figsize=(15,10),sharex=True)

plots=[blue, green, hene]
colors=['blue', 'green', 'red']
labels=['Blue Filter', 'Green Filter', 'He-Ne Laser']

for i,ax in enumerate(axs):
    axs[i].plot(x,plots[i], color=colors[i],label=labels[i])
    axs[i].legend(loc="upper right")
axs.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

Is there any way that I can remove the ticks and names of points on the x and/or y axes? The last line of code is from another question where the axis is created with plt.gca() so it doesn't work. Can I do this while using plt.subplots or should I just use plt.gca()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely do this. Here is the example. You can separately turn of or on any axis ticks using matplotlib `setp` function.

For your case, just remove last line from your code.

```py
for i,ax in enumerate(axs):
    axs[i].plot(t,s1, color=colors[i],label=labels[i])
    axs[i].legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.setp(axs[i].get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(axs[i].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
```

[image: OutputImage]

**P.S.:** I don't have your dataset so use random dataset.